# Unable to install GoClipse

Tags: eclipse, go, goclipse

I am trying to install Goclipse to use my STS for building go Projects .

I am trying to install the plugin from eclipse marketplace but getting this error

**Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: GoClipse 0.16.0.v201606221240 (goclipse_feature.feature.group 0.16.0.v201606221240)
  Missing requirement: GoClipse 0.16.0.v201606221240 (goclipse_feature.feature.group 0.16.0.v201606221240) requires 'org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [4.5.0,5.0.0)' but it could not be found**

Can anyone suggest how to fix this ?

Help is appreciated

Comment: I have a very similar problem (in Eclipse Mars).  The only GoClipse version available is 0.16.1.  Missing dependency:  'org.eclipse.cdt.gnu.dsf.feature.group [9.0.0,10.0.0)' but it could not be found

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**'org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [4.5.0,5.0.0)' but it could not be found.**

You need Eclipse Mars (4.5) or Neon (4.6) for GoClipse. (Note: for GoClipse 0.16.0, if you download an Eclipse Neon package make sure it does not contain CDT already, or there will be a conflict with CDT 9.0 on installation. The next GoClipse version will have all this fixed.)

Answer (score -1):

I always install Eclipse plugins through the "Install new software" feature instead of the market place.

With Goclipse this wasn't the exception and it worked just fine for me by resolving all dependencies.

You can follow this steps (from the Goclipse docs at https://github.com/GoClipse/goclipse/blob/latest/documentation/Installation.md#installation)

- Start Eclipse, go to Help -> Install New Software...
- Click the Add... button, then enter the Update Site URL: http://goclipse.github.io/releases/ in the Location field, click OK.
- Select the recently added update site in the Work with: dropdown. Type GoClipse in the filter box. Now the Goclipse feature should appear below.
  Select the GoClipse feature, and complete the wizard.
- Dependencies such as CDT will automatically be added during installation.
- Restart Eclipse.

Comment: I already tried this but it gaves the same error :( 

What version of eclipse do you use?

Comment: Eclipse Platform 4.5.2.M20160212-1500 org.eclipse.platform.ide Eclipse.org